# Define preprocessor symbol as a string containing spaces

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, preprocessor, whitespace

I'm working on a legacy project (in C, if that matters) that requires the use of MS Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Specifically, one tool in the toolchain generates an MSVC makefile (`.mak`), which is then converted by a wizard in MSVC2008 to a project file (`.vcproj`), where it can be compiled/debugged.

I'm trying to define a pre-processor symbol (`/D`), which via the template makefile is set equal to an environment variable. The value of this environment variable is a string, possibly containing spaces.

I can't seem to find the right syntax for this, both by experiment or via Google. The wizard seems to be messing up quotes and spaces in a not-so-predictable manner...For example, if I put in the (generated) makefile

```
/D "MYSYMBOL=\"my string\"" /D "MYOTHERSYMBOL=\"someOtherString\"
```

Visual Studio's wizard erroneously puts the following in the project file:

```
/D /D "MYSYMBOL=\" my string\"" "MYOTHERSYMBOL=\" someOtherString\"
```

(note also the spaces after the escaped quotes).

Similarly:

```
input : /D "MYSYMBOL=\"my string\"" /D "MYOTHERSYMBOL=\"someOtherString\"
output: /D /D "MYSYMBOL=\" my string\"" "MYOTHERSYMBOL=\" someOtherString\" 

input : /D"MYSYMBOL=\"my string\"" /D"MYOTHERSYMBOL=\"someOtherString\"
output: /D"MYSYMBOL=\"my /D"MYOTHERSYMBOL=\"someOtherString\" string\""

input : /DMYSYMBOL=\"my string\" /DMYOTHERSYMBOL=\"someOtherString\
output: /DMYSYMBOL=\"my /DMYOTHERSYMBOL=\"someOtherString\" string\"

input : /DMYSYMBOL="""my string""" /DMYOTHERSYMBOL="""someOtherString"""
output: /DMYSYMBOL="""my /DMYOTHERSYMBOL="""someOtherString""" string"""

...etc.
```

Is there a way to do this? Or should I follow a whole different approach altogether to get the environment variable in?

Comment: This seems like a problem / bug in the "wizard".  I don't know how we can be expected to help you with that.

Comment: @MadScientist  I know, it's not the only shortcoming in MSVC2008 I've found :) I'm just putting it out into the world to see if anyone's encountered the same problem before and has managed to solve it somehow. Hence also my last sentence: maybe there is a different approach altogether?